# Execute store procedure with php and odbc

Tags: php, odbc

I am trying to use PHP with ODBC, but the following code is not working.

Procedure `(CALL AU_GPF_BILL_Procedure(@MUniqueIdentifier))` is not being called.

```
$uniqueIdentifier = 'GPF_201712785';
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'CALL AU_GPF_BILL_Procedure(@MUniqueIdentifier)');
echo $stmt;
$str = odbc_execute($stmt, $uniqueIdentifier);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Can you try changing the parameter `@MUniqueIdentifier` to ? as this is more normal for PHP and prepared statements.

Comment: I tried it still not working

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if your procedure only uses IN parameters. You cannot call stored procedures which use OUT or INOUT parameters using odbc.

Parameters need to be supplied in an array.

```
$uniqueIdentifier = 'GPF_201712785';
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'CALL AU_GPF_BILL_Procedure(?)');
if(odbc_execute($stmt, array($uniqueIdentifier))) {
    $row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt);
    // Whatever
}
```